# How to clear a file using FILE*

Tags: c++

I am developing a study project. It includes registration, authorization, and saving records of customer. In my project reading the information from file using fstream is not working so I use FILE* method. And I need to clear all data in file to rewrite it for saving new records.

There is a question. How to clear it? I found a lot of examples how to do this but all of their are for using fstream. Is it real to do using FILE* ?

Here is some code:

```
FILE* Usrs = fopen("Users.dat", "rb");
        StructForReg Array[100];
        StructForReg Perenos;
        int i = 0;
        while (!!(feof(Usrs) == 0))
        {
            fread(&Perenos, sizeof(StructForReg), 15, Usrs);
            Array[i] = Perenos;
            i += 1;
        }
        fclose(Usrs);
//here must be a code with clearing and rewriting
```

Comment: See: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/253056)

Answer (score 1):

> How to clear a file using FILE*?
>
> And I need to clear all data in file to rewrite it for saving new records.

Just open with using `"w"` (or `"wb"`) mode. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) the `w` mode destroys file contents if the file exists. If the file does not exists, it will create a new one.

Comment: After trying to do this now I have a new error. When I opened this file using ```"wb"``` It shows an error in ```xmemory0``` with this text: ```Attempting to read or write to a protected memory. This often indicates that another memory is corrupted```.

Comment: Now after deleting this code that includes opening with ```"wb"``` It shows this error every time I try to read information from file

Answer (score 1):

See the manpage for [fopen](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen). `"w"` or `"w+"` in the flags causes the file to get truncated.